# Bash integer and string conditional with both && and || in if statement

Tags: string, bash, integer, conditional-statements

In a Bash script, I have the following conditional:

```
if [ $cnt -eq 1 ] && [[ $str != *"something 1"* || $str != *"something 2"* ]]
```

It is not working as expected.  Is this possible in Bash?  If so, what is the correct syntax?  The desired behavior is that the if statement returns true if `$cnt -eq 1` is true and either `$str != *"something 1"*` or `$str != *"something 2"*` is true.

Comment: The syntax is fine; why do you think it is wrong? Provide values of `$cnt` and `$str` for which the result is not what you expect, along with the expected value.

Comment: well -- `[ $cnt -eq 1 ]` is not *quite* fine, inasmuch as it'll throw a syntax error rather than doing something more useful if `cnt` is empty, undefined, or expands to multiple words. `[ "$cnt" -eq 1 ]` would avoid those cases, whereas `(( cnt == 1 ))` would be cleaner to read (and treat an unset value as if it were 0). But assuming that there really *is* a single numeric value in that variable, and `IFS` doesn't contain any digits also found in that number, then the lack of quotes there won't cause any immediate bug, so we're still lacking a reproducer here.

Comment: ...more bluntly: "It doesn't work" is not a bug report.

Comment: (To take a guess: Are you running your script with `sh yourscript`, or starting it with `#!/bin/sh`? If the interpreter used is `sh` rather than `bash`, then *it's not a bash script*, and you can't use bash-specific syntax such as `[[ ]]`).

Comment: Sample values for which the result is not what I expect: $cnt = 1, $str = "http://www.google.com/something 1/endofurl"
I expect the if statement to be true in this case but it's false when I run the script.

Comment: The script starts with #!/bin/bash and I'm running it with ./myscript.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a syntax problem, I'm pretty sure it's a logic problem. The expression `[[ $str != *"something 1"* || $str != *"something 2"* ]]` is true unless `$str` matches *both* patterns. Consider:

```
$ str="foo no pattern bar"
$ [[ $str != *"something 1"* || $str != *"something 2"* ]] && echo true || echo false
true
$ str="foo something 1 bar"
$ [[ $str != *"something 1"* || $str != *"something 2"* ]] && echo true || echo false
true
$ str="foo something 2 bar"
$ [[ $str != *"something 1"* || $str != *"something 2"* ]] && echo true || echo false
true
$ str="foo something 1 something 2 bar"
$ [[ $str != *"something 1"* || $str != *"something 2"* ]] && echo true || echo false
false
```

I think what you want is something that's true if `$str` doesn't match either pattern, which means you need `&&` instead of `||`:

```
$ str="foo no pattern bar"
$ [[ $str != *"something 1"* && $str != *"something 2"* ]] && echo true || echo false
true
$ str="foo something 1 bar"
$ [[ $str != *"something 1"* && $str != *"something 2"* ]] && echo true || echo false
false
$ str="foo something 2 bar"
$ [[ $str != *"something 1"* && $str != *"something 2"* ]] && echo true || echo false
false
```

To understand why this is, check [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), one of which says that "not (A or B)" is the same as "(not A) and (not B)".

Comment: Hi Gordon, you are right!  The change from || to && fixed my problem.  Thank you!